# Icons for undo, redo etc

Tags: c#, icons

I'm developing C# in Visual Studio 2013 Express. I need icons for basic functions.

I can add standard items to my toolbar but they don't contain undo and redo. I'd also like to add icons to my menus too.

Where can I find them?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you need to find icons to add to your toolbar. Here: http://images.google.com/

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They used to be included with visual studio but aren't for more recent versions. You can get the ones in VS 2012 at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825